# NVIDIA drivers don't work after kernel update to 5.11

Tags: nvidia

After installing the kernel update to 5.11 in order to fix touchpad on Lenovo Legion 5, NVIDIA drivers stopped working, hence disallowing me to use a dual monitor setup.

Comment: Where did you get 5.11? No supported release of Ubuntu ships with the 5.11 kernel.

Comment: It is expected that Nvidia drivers don't support this kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Kernel 5.11 is still just in RC step (release candidate) thus Nvidia doesn't have to support it yet.

Go with 5.10.x, everything works just fine there. For dual monitor you might want to switch primary GPU.

Comment: just my 2 cents: 5.10.10-051010-generic works fine with AMD processor GPU + discrete graphics (GTX 1650) and dual monitor, no fresher kernel works with this setup as of today, so if you havetrouble with more recent kernel, install this one using mainline package.